# Rails - Call a method form a model or helper with an alias

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a helper called `GlobalHelper`.

There are a couple of constants (e.g. `GLOBAL_URL`) and methods (e.g. `self.get_url`) in it.

I'm trying to make an alias or an equivalent of the macros in C (`#define URL`) to access the constant and methods from any of my views and controllers easily.

For now I have to do it like this:

```
GlobalHelper.get_url(GlobalHelper::URL_TYPE_PAGE, ["page1"])
```

And I want to get rid of the `GlobalHelper` everywhere with alias/macro to get a code like this instead:

```
aliasmethod(aliasconstant, ["page1"])
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You shouldn't do this. It's better to be explicit. If you really must, then use concerns, and mix them into the classes where you're consuming the `GlobalHelper` module.

Comment: There are no C-like macros in ruby, so textual substitution is out of the question. And yes, do what @meagar says. You'll need to read up on "concerns" and "mixins".

Comment: @SergioTulentsev there are no macros in [tag:c] neither. There is a macro preprocessor, that could be involved into build chain. The aforementioned preprocessor could be easily run on any files, including ruby ones, while macros are of valid syntax. _The above is just a correction and should not be treated as a way to go by any means :)_

Comment: @mudasobwa: I stand corrected :)

Comment: @meagar “It's better to be explicit.”—Rails framework is _literally everywhere_ doing exactly that, building creepy names like `url_for_whatever_with_whistles` instead of being explicit.

Comment: @mudasobwa Rails does this in a limited number of thoughtful ways to make the developer's life easier. Rails has a massive test suite, excellent documentation of its conventions, and the kinds of implicit "magic" it provides have been debated over for hundreds of thousands of man hours before arriving in their current state. Rails can be implicit, application code should be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

ruby is not c, so you should take a look how to write ideomatic ruby code before trying to bring such concepts into your project.

since i don't know what exactly your get_url method does, i can only give limited recommendations.

one thing that would probably result in much nicer code is using symbols instead of constants:

```
GlobalHelper.get_url(:page, ["page1"])
```

when using a `Module` instead of `Class` you can include it and call the method directly:

```
include GlobalHelper
get_url(...)
```

these are just examples of what could be done. not saying that this is better than explicitly calling `GlobalHelper` directly. nothing wrong with that at all.